# Attempting a transpose by performing multiple joins of table on subsets of same table in Hive

Tags: join, hive, transpose

I'm attempting to perform a transpose on the column `date` by performing multiple joins of my table `data_A` on subsets of the same table:

Here's the code to create my test dataset, which contains duplicate records for every value of `count`:

```
create table database.data_A (member_id string, x1 int, x2 int, count int, date date);
insert into table database.data_A
select 'A0001',1, 10, 1, '2017-01-01' 
union all
select 'A0001',1, 10, 2, '2017-07-01'
union all
select 'A0001',2, 20, 1, '2017-01-01'
union all
select 'A0001',2, 20, 2, '2017-07-01'
union all
select 'B0001',3, 50, 1, '2017-03-01'
union all
select 'C0001',4, 100, 1, '2017-04-01'
union all
select 'D0001',5, 200, 1, '2017-10-01' 
union all
select 'D0001',5, 200, 2, '2017-11-01'
union all
select 'D0001',5, 200, 3, '2017-12-01'
union all
select 'D0001',6, 500, 1, '2017-10-01'
union all
select 'D0001',6, 500, 2, '2017-11-01'
union all
select 'D0001',6, 500, 3, '2017-12-01'
union all
select 'D0001',7, 1000, 1, '2017-10-01'
union all
select 'D0001',7, 1000, 2, '2017-11-01'
union all
select 'D0001',7, 1000, 3, '2017-12-01';
```

I'd like to transpose the data into this:

```
member_id x1 x2 date1 date2 date3     
'A0001', 1, 10, '2017-01-01' '2017-07-01' . 
'A0001', 2, 20, '2017-01-01' '2017-07-01' .
'B0001', 3, 50, '2017-03-01' . . 
'C0001', 4, 100, '2017-04-01' . . 
'D0001', 5, 200, '2017-10-01' '2017-11-01' '2017-12-01'
'D0001', 6, 500, '2017-10-01' '2017-11-01' '2017-12-01'
'D0001', 7, 1000, '2017-10-01' '2017-11-01' '2017-12-01'
```

My first program (which was not successful):

```
create table database.data_B as 
select a.member_id, a.x1, a.x2, a.date_1, b.date_2, c.date_3
from (select member_id, x1, x2, date as date_1 from database.data_A where count=1) as a
left join
(select member_id, date as date_2 from database.data_A where count=2) as b
on (a.member_id=b.member_id)
left join 
(select member_id, date as date_3 from database.data_A where count=3) as c
on (a.member_id=c.member_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below will do the job.

```
 select
 member_id,
 x1,
 x2,
 max(case when count=1 then date1 else '.' end) as date11,
 max(case when count=2 then date1 else '.' end) as date2,
 max(case when count=3 then date1 else '.' end) as date3
 from data_A
 group by member_id,x1, x2
```

Comment: Thanks Vijiy - your code almost worked - after adding collect_set statements and substituting NULL for '.' I was able to perform the transpose: select member_id, x1, x2,
collect_set(date_1)[0] as date_1_sum,
collect_set(date_2)[0] as date_2_sum,
collect_set(date_3)[0] as date_3_sum
from (
select member_id, x1, x2,
case when event_count=1 then event_date end as date_1,
case when event_count=2 then event_date end as date_2,
case when event_count=3 then event_date end as date_3
from hpa_datsci_scratch.data_A) t1
group by member_id, x1, x2